# Can I craft armor that can use Epic Gems?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I craft almost all my own armor and weapons.  I've recently unlocked the ability to craft epic gems.  I can include gems in my armor and weapons, but I can't seem to combine the two.

Is there any way to use an epic gem in a weapon or armor piece that I craft?  If not, how do I go about using epic gems?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Epic gems are limited to chest slots only. Blacksmithing does not get around this limit.

So, just make sure you're smithing a chest piece, and the gems should show up.

Answer (score 0):

Epic gems can only be fitted in a chest piece but there are other similar bonus gems that can go in other items when crafting so it's not a big loss only being able to put epic gems in chest pieces. :]